# How to store and use two variable from a csv file for each line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a csv file `A.csv` (separator : `,`):

```
sample,run
2071410189,RUN120
2071436273,RUN119
2071507844,RUN120
2071627356,RUN120
2071627370,RUN118
```

And I want to concatenate a file that each "sample" have and in order to do that I have to use both column information for construct the path.
Example for each line of `A.csv`

```
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071410189_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN119_*/analyse/2071436273_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071507844_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071627356_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN118_*/analyse/2071627370_*_*/*consensus.fasta
```

I know how to do a loop for several file but I don't know how to do it for each line of a same file (`A.csv`). Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try

```
awk -F, '{print "home/" $2 "_*/analyse/" $1 "_*_*/*consensus.fasta"}' file
```

which is simply adding some string constants to your file. `awk` by itself loops through every line of an input file.

**EDIT:**
I read from your comments, @nstatam, that you want to construct from your input file a set of paths to files, and then concatenate all those files into a new one. You could try this one, by adding each path to `awk`'s argument list, and then print all of them to stdout (which can / should be redirected into the desired file):

```
awk -F, '
FNR==NR {ARGV[ARGC++] = "home/" $2 "_*/analyse/" $1 "_*_*/*consensus.fasta"
         next}
1
' file
```

Tested on `mawk` 1.3.4 20200120 (Ubuntu) and `awk` version 20110810 (FreeBSD)
Pls. be aware that this "adding to the argument list" doesn't work on all `awk` versions out there.

Comment: Thanks for the awk command but now that I have a list of path to the different `.fasta` file, how to `cat` this list in order to have one file ?

Comment: @nstatam use `xargs`: `awk -F, '...' file | xargs cat > allfilesconcatenated.txt`

Comment: What I want is not to have the path in a single file but to have the content of each path into one file. When I'm using `xargs cat > bla.txt` I have the "no such file or directory" errors and when I'm using `'....' file >>output` that only cat the path into the file. Do you know how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @nstatam: pls see my EDITed post.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do as follows.
Here we reconstruct $0 field by field
and output with slash as output field separator.

```
awk -F "," -v s="_*" '
{
  t = "home,"$2 s",analyse,"$1 s s",*consensus.fasta"
  split(t,a);$0=""
  for (i=1; i in a; i++) $(i) = a[i]
}
1' OFS=/ A.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to read each line of your file, pick out the two fields from the line, and do something with the files matching the pattern that you show, then you may do that like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

tail -n +2 file.csv |
while IFS=, read -r number run
do
        printf 'Got number="%s" and run="%s"\n' "$number" "$run"

        for name in home/"$run"_*/analyse/"$number"_*_*/*consensus.fasta
        do
                [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue

                # Call program to process FastA file "$name".
                printf 'Would process "%s"\n' "$name"
        done
done
```

This skips the header line of `file.csv` using `tail`, and then parses each line into two comma-delimited fields that are stored in the shell variable `number` and `run`.

For each `$number` and `$run` read from `file.csv`,the script then loops over the names matching the pattern `home/"$run"_*/analyse/"$number"_*_*/*consensus.fasta`.  If the pattern matches, a simple message is printed for each match (you may choose to do something else).

An alternative script that assumes you may want to pass all matching files to a single invocation of some program, for each line read from `file.csv` (if the pattern matches any names at all):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

tail -n +2 file.csv |
while IFS=, read -r number run
do
        printf 'Got number="%s" and run="%s"\n' "$number" "$run"

        set -- home/"$run"_*/analyse/"$number"_*_*/*consensus.fasta
        [ ! -e "$1" ] && continue

        # Call your command with the list of FastA files, "$@".
        printf 'Would process "%s"\n' "$@"

        # Other example:
        # cat "$@" >"$run"-"$number"-consensus.fasta
done
```

If all you want to do is to concatenate *all* FastA files, then possibly do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

tail -n +2 file.csv |
while IFS=, read -r number run
do
        set -- home/"$run"_*/analyse/"$number"_*_*/*consensus.fasta
        [ ! -e "$1" ] && continue
        cat "$@"
done >consensus.fasta
```

Or, if you are *absolutely certain* that these patterns always will match some file (or you're not too worried about a few "no such file or directory" errors):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

tail -n +2 file.csv |
while IFS=, read -r number run
do
        cat home/"$run"_*/analyse/"$number"_*_*/*consensus.fasta
done >consensus.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('file.txt','r')
k.readline()
for i in k:
        var_fin=i.strip().split(',')
        var_fj="home/{0}_*/analyse/{1}_*_*/*consensus.fasta".format(var_fin[1],var_fin[0])
        print var_fj
```

output

```
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071410189_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN119_*/analyse/2071436273_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071507844_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN120_*/analyse/2071627356_*_*/*consensus.fasta
home/RUN118_*/analyse/2071627370_*_*/*consensus.fasta
```